# Where is the option to share with "anyone, even anonymous"? Gsuite web app deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-gsuite

I've been developing in GAS in the past 4 years or so.
Not so long ago we had the option to make the web app accessible to "anyone, even anonymous" but now I can't find it.

[image]

Can someone please help and tell me why was that change and what to do if I want the app to be accessible by anonymous users? Couldn't find a single thing in the docs (possibly outdated) or in their forums

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

These are the corresponding options for web app access between the Legacy
IDE and the new IDE:

| Legacy IDE | New IDE |
| --- | --- |
| Only Myself | Only Myself |
| Anyone within Domain | Anyone within Domain |
| Anyone | Anyone with Google Account |
| Anyone, even anonymous | Anyone |

**New IDE:**

[image]

**Legacy IDE:**

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Legacy had: "anyone" and "anyone, even anonymous"
I've tried "anyone" and it asks me to log in... so that doesn't work...

Comment: Legacy IDE "Anyone" corresponds to "Anyone with a Google Account" in new IDE. Apologies for the confusion, I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks!
Just re-deployed and it works

Comment: Very much appreciated!